# Rails 4, Capistrano 3 and Dotenv - How to deploy using server-side .env file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3

I have a Rails 4 app with Dotenv gem to read variables from the file `.env`.

There are some variables I've set in order to have a mysql user other than "root" for my rails app, for example:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_USER='rootuser'
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='rootpassword'
APP_DATABASE_USER='mydbuser'
APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD='userpassword'
```

I've also created a bash script to create the mysql user under `scripts/database_setup.bash`

```
#!/bin/bash
source ../.env
# creates the user
mysql -u${MYSQL_ROOT_USER} --password="${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}" -e "CREATE USER '${APP_DATABASE_USER}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD}';"
# grants permission
mysql -u${MYSQL_ROOT_USER} --password="${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}" -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \`myapp\_%\`.* TO '${APP_DATABASE_USER}'@'localhost';"
```

On the server side, Capistrano deploys to `/home/myuser/apps/myapp/

I have three questions:

1. Where is the best place to put my server-side `.env` file? Right now I'm putting it in `/home/myuser/apps/myapp/` directory.
2. How can I tell Capistrano to copy it to Rails root directory?
3. How can I tell Capistrano to execute my bash script before running migrations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In production environment I think you shouldn't use `.env` at all.

Probably it's better to put the ENV vars in:

`/etc/environment`

by writing your variables like this:

`export ENV_VARIABLE=value`

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is still having troubles with this, here is how I got my `.env` working in production with Capistrano 3.5+:

Add your `.env.production` to `/shared` directory in production. Then, inside the deployment script, use Capistrano's `append` command to load linked files from the `/shared` directory like so:

```
append :linked_files, ".env.production"
```

Run the standard deploy (`cap production deploy`)

You can test whether env vars were appended by launching the rails console in production mode (`rails c p`) from inside the `/current` directory.

Comment: can you tell about the detail of how I test? what do I have to type?  - You can test whether env vars were appended by launching the rails console in production mode (rails c p) from inside the /current directory.

Comment: SSH into your server, `cd` into `/current` and launch `rails console`. Once you're in`pry` or `irb`, test your env by typing `ENV['YOUR_ENV_VAR']`

Comment: somehow, I can't type `rails c` in my production server. but your answer worked. 

~/myapp/current$ rails c
Traceback (most recent call last):
 4: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
 3: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
 2: from /home/deploy/myapp/releases/20191129015922/bin/spring:8:in `<top (required)>'
 1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)

Comment: @JinLim it looks like `bundler` is not installed. Try installing bundler.

Comment: You might to run it like this: `bundle exec rails console -e production`